# Minimum thickness for a pipe fitting?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, plumbing

I need to thread a 1/4 bsp (M12) into a 4mm thick aluminium end plate. The working fluid is water at 90 degrees celsius. Is the end plate thick enough to adequately seal the flow or should I consider welding a cylindrical extrusion onto the plate?

Comment: The thickness would depend on both the temperature and pressure the plate must withstand.

Answer (score 0):

Weld a boss onto the plate, or you could make a nut to go on the back if the fitting has a flange.

A nut can be made from aluminium: use hex bar stock either accept the size or machine / file to the size desired and drill then tap the hole.

Comment: Latter sounds feasible, but the plate in question is AL and nuts are usually steel? Any way to work around it?

Comment: I did say "make a nut" so make one in aluminium - hex bar, drill a hole aqnd tap...